# Solving $\int_{\frac{1}{3\sqrt3}}^{3\sqrt3}\cfrac{1}{x^{4/3}+x^{2/3}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to compute the following integral $$\int_{\frac{1}{3\sqrt3}}^{3\sqrt3}\cfrac{1}{x^{4/3}+x^{2/3}}dx$$
I have tried a variety of substitution methods. I tried letting $u=1+x^{2/3}$ because $x^{4/3}+x^{2/3}=x^{2/3}(1+x^{2/3})$, allowing me to take a partial fraction from $$\cfrac32\int_{4/3}^{4}\cfrac{(u-1)^{1/2}}{u(u-1)}du$$ to $$\cfrac32\int_{4/3}^{4}\cfrac{1}{u-1}-\cfrac1u du$$
And this gets me about $1.6479$, but my calculator says the answer is exactly $\frac12\pi$.

Comment: How did you get from a term $\dfrac{(u-1)^{1/2}}{u(u-1)}$ to $\dfrac1{u-1}-\dfrac1u$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I realized I made a mistake in my partial fraction. I took $\cfrac{(u-1)^{1/2}}{u(u-1)}=\cfrac{1}{u}(u-1)^{1/2-1}=\cfrac{1}{u(u-1)^{1/2}}$ but accidentally set $A=u, B=(u-1)$ instead of $B=(u-1)^{1/2}$, which wouldn't have worked anyway since the exponent is not an integer

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify matters by the substitution $x=t^3$. This means that $dx=3t^2dt$. The upper limit is $\displaystyle{3\sqrt3=3^1\cdot3^\frac12=3^\frac32}$. Therefore, the substitution turns this limit into $\sqrt3$. The integral becomes:
$$\int_{\frac1{\sqrt3}}^\sqrt3\frac{3x^2}{x^4+x^2}dx=3\int_{\frac1{\sqrt3}}^\sqrt3\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=3(\arctan(\sqrt3)-\arctan(\frac1{\sqrt3}))=3(\frac\pi3-\frac\pi6)=\frac\pi2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\cfrac{1}{x^{4/3}+x^{2/3}}dx=\int\cfrac{1}{x^{2/3}(x^{2/3}+1)}dx=\int\cfrac{3d(x^{1/3})}{x^{2/3}+1}dx=3\int\cfrac{du}{u^2+1}dx=3\arctan(x^{1/3})$$ Plugging in the limits, it does evaluate to $\pi \over 2$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $\ u = x^{\frac{1}{3}}.\ $ Then the integral becomes:

$$\int \frac{1}{u^4 + u^2}\ \cdot\ 3u^2\ du\ =\ 3\int \frac{1}{u^2 + 1}\ du\ =\ 3\arctan(u) + c. $$

I'll leave you to figure out the limits and hence the value of the definite integral.